# what is the proper union or sql construct to resolve these 2 datasets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table UserParent:

```
Id, FirstName, LastName
```

I have a table UserChild:

```
Id, ParentUserId (FK), ChildAttributeX
```

I have the following sample SQL:

```
SELECT Id, 0 ChildUserId, FirstName, LastName, NULL FROM UserParent
UNION
SELECT ParentUserId, Id, FirstName, LastName, ChildAttributeX FROM UserChild
```

Some Users may exist in both tables. All Users are stored with basic info in UserParent although some Users who have ChildAttributeX will have a FK ref to the UserParent in UserChild along with the ChildAttributeX in UserChild.

How can I resolve this as part of a UNION or some other SQL technique so all Users are included in the result set, without duplicate users?

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: Do `UserParent` and `UserChild` actually store different data (apart from who the parent of the child is)? If not, then there's no need for 2 tables, you can have one table that has a self referencing key. Also, `UserParent` implies it has a column for child. If a Parent has more than 1 child, how are you storing that data? Adding a 2nd row for the same Parent? (if so, that's a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.  If all records must exist in parent table, this will return all records from parent, and any record that exist in child table, but only unique records (DISTINCT does that).

```
SELECT DISTINCT UP.ID, UP.FirstName, UP.LastName
FROM UserParent UP
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserChild UC ON UP.ID = UC.ParentUserID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all the records present in both table, you can try below query:

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(UP.Id,UC.ParentUserId),
 0 ChildUserId,
 (UP.FirstName,UC.FirstName),
 (UP.LastName,UC.LastName),
 NULL FROM 
       UserParent UP 
         FULL OUTER JOIN 
            UserChild UC 
             ON UC.ParentUserId = UP.ID
```